# Jekyll For Loop to include all of a directory

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am using Jekyll to create a static page on GitHub, I've setup my default layout and index.html page.

I want to create a folder called 'sections' and store a load of .html files which are basically different sections to a guide that I'm making. The purpose of this is so that I can then include the whole of 'sections' into my main index.html using a Jekyll for loop. I want to keep all of my sections inside the section folder to make it more manageable.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory structure of Jekyll is not something you can change according to your convenience. If you want to have each of the `html` pages as a separate page in your website, you have do is put your `html` pages in the `_posts` directory in your project and use the `for` loop like this to include their links in `index.html`:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
    <!-- link to each post in index.html -->
    <a href="{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to put the contents of each `html` file in `index.html`, then you cannot use `_posts` for that. In that case, you need to use the `_includes` directory, and do something like:

```
... 
{% include page1.html %}
{% include page2.html %}
{% include page3.html %}
...
```

See the [Jekyll directory structure doc](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/).

Comment: Say I have *.html files within _posts can I just include all of them the main index.html?